# Faz sentido utilizar uma api para acessar outra api? (bematec one no caso)

Tags: php, c#, api, visual-basic-6

Me pediram para fazer uma API aqui onde trabalho para poder integrar alguns sistemas com a nfce. Para isso, contrataram a api one. Seguem mais informações aqui: http://bematechpartners.com.br/portalPartners/index.php/api-one-central-download/.

A dúvida real é como e pq eu deveria fazer uma API para acessar outra API? Não seria mais fácil os programas antigos acessarem diretamente essa api one da bematec?

Tem programas feitos em vb, outros em c# e um php.

EDIT: Vou tentar aplicar uma dessas formas aqui. Obrigado a quem respondeu! https://sensedia.com/blog/apis/estrategias-sem-impacto-no-backend-para-expor-apis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sim.**

**Criar uma interface de abstração para sistemas legados acessarem novos serviços é algo comum, senão até mais recomendável, quando:**

- O custo de alterar os sistemas legados é muito significativo
- A API que está consumindo pode mudar com frequência, ou é instável e poderia quebrar suas aplicações de alguma forma
- Você quer implementar uma funcionalidade extra que não seria possível nos sistemas legados

  - Controle de Nível de acesso
  - Obtenção de métricas
  - Cacheamento de requisições (tanto para buscar dados, como para enviar dados)

Esses são alguns dos motivos. Sistemas legados em geral agravam a necessidade dessas interfaces (que como @Afonso disse, servem como [Padrão de projeto Façade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A7ade)).

Existem motivos para não fazer isso, sendo o mais óbvio ser menos trabalhoso implementar logo as chamadas nos seus programas antigos:

- *Ter pontos contrários aos que citei acima*
- Os sistemas legados já não acessavam alguma interface padrão antes, até mesmo a programação para acessar sua API interna da empresa iria requerer trabalho

---

Essa resposta é mais complexa e isso aqui foi um resumo. Mas na dúvida, faça o que pareceria dar menos trabalho. Mas se alguém que trabalhou com sistema antigo na sua empresa diz que daria menos trabalho fazer algo novo (que, olhe, pelo que disse teriam falado ser uma opção a ser escolhida), é uma boa indicação do que você não sabe das dificuldades técnicas

Comment: Obrigado, realmente não sei muito bem das dificuldades técnicas, até porque nunca mexi no código desses sistemas antigos (e nem tenho permissão), sou meio novo na empresa.

Answer (score 0):

Parece-me que poderá valer a pena para integrar de forma centralizada todos os sistemas. Vale a pena ver o padrão de desenho Fascade - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/facade_pattern.htm

> Facade pattern hides the complexities of the system and provides an
>   interface to the client using which the client can access the system.
>   This type of design pattern comes under structural pattern as this
>   pattern adds an interface to existing system to hide its complexities.
>
> This pattern involves a single class which provides simplified methods
>   required by client and delegates calls to methods of existing system
>   classes.

Comment: no caso esqueci de falar que a api n vai ter acesso a banco, me parece algo anormal.
parece interessante o uso do facade, vou dar uma olhada